# How delete char* array on mac osx using xcode?

Tags: c++

```
int nSize; 
QString str; 
char *p = new char[nSize]; 
p = str.toLocal8bit.data();
delete[] p;
```

I got a debug error when I tried to delete a char array in Xcode 5.0.2 but this char array is successfully deleted in Xcode 3.0.2.

Comment: Are you intentionally using C++? It is best to mark the language with a tag in a question like this.

Comment: i dont get why you would do such things as using a `QString` copy its content to a `char*` and handle that memory when the starting `QString` would deal with that for you. If some funciton needs a `char*` then use `QString::toLocal8Bit()` and you should be good to go

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line

```
p = str.toLocal8bit.data();
```

overwrites the pointer that you got from `new`. When you delete `p` you're deleting memory you don't control.

If you actually need a copy of the string data, you can use `memcpy` or `strcpy` to copy from the string to your array (instead of assigning).

If you don't actually need a copy, you could do:

```
const char* p = str.toLocal8bit.data();
```

Answer (score 7):

If it's deleted successfully anywhere, that's a bug.

```
char* p = new char[nSize];
```

So far so good.  p is a char array.

```
p = str.toLocal8bit.data();
```

p now points to (presumably) some underlying data from str.toLocal8bit.  You now have no way to reference the memory you just allocated.

```
delete[] p;
```

You've now deleted some other object's memory.